# Swift 4 Key Value Dictionary stored in User Defaults

Tags: ios, swift4, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I am new to Swift and have a requirement to store a database of key value pairs. The key value pairs are a name with a corresponding 4 digit number in database that remains in memory after the app is excited. I am thinking to use a dictionary with the name as the key and the 4 digit numbers as the value. These are then stored in the iPad flash memory using the user defaults class.

Below is the code that I’ve currently  developed. The code that adds to the database compiles ok but the code that checks the name and number for a match in the database won't compile due to the following message (Value of optional type '[Any]?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?) which is because of this line of code (if let databaseCheck = database[name]). Ive obviously tried unwrapping but can't seem to shake the error message.

Anyone got any ideas whats causing the error or any issues with the approach?

```
public func checkDatabaseMatch( _ name: String, _ number: String) -> Bool
{
   var foundInDatabaseFlag: Bool = false

   let database = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "Database")

   if let databaseCheck = database[name]
   {
      if (databaseCheck == number)
      {
         foundInDatabaseFlag = true
      }
   }

   return foundInDatabaseFlag
 }

public func saveToDatabase( _ name: String, _ number: String)
{
   var newEntry: [String: String] = [:]

   newEntry[name] = number

   UserDefaults.standard.set(newEntry, forKey: "Database")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a major mistake. You save a dictionary but retrieve an array.

Apart from that a dictionary retrieved from `UserDefaults` is `[String:Any]` by default, you have to conditional downcast the object.

The code checks if there is a dictionary in `UserDefaults` and if there is the requested key in one expression

```
public func checkDatabaseMatch( _ name: String, _ number: String) -> Bool
{
   guard let database = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "Database") as? [String:String],
      let databaseCheck = database[name] else { return false }

   return databaseCheck == number
}
```

Another mistake is that you are always overwriting the entire dictionary in `UserDefaults`. If you want to save multiple key-value pairs you have to read the dictionary first.

```
public func saveToDatabase( _ name: String, _ number: String)
{
   var newEntry : [String: String] 
   if let database = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "Database") as? [String:String] {
      newEntry = database
   } else {
      newEntry = [:]
   }     
   newEntry[name] = number

   UserDefaults.standard.set(newEntry, forKey: "Database")
}
```

Side note: The parameter labels are highly recommended in Swift for better readability.

Comment: Thanks vadian, worked a treat!! :), can't believe I was retreving an array and not a dictionary. Noted regarding the labels in Swift. Thanks for all your help.